# Fetch data from server on scrolling in celltable gwt

Tags: gwt

I need to implement a feature in GWT which is already existing in smartgwt. In smartgwt, we can set a maximum limit of records in a grid is 75. When the record count reaches 75 while scrolling, it again requests the server and fetches another 75 records. Similar functionality I have to implement in GWT. ie, while scrolling, i have to fetch records from server for every 75 records. Is it possible?? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use the ScrollPanel for check when the user reache the end of the scoll.

You can try this example of code, and adapt it to your case :

```
String loremIpsum = "a long text..."; // add a long text here for test
ScrollPanel sPanelTest = new ScrollPanel(loremIpsum);
sPanelTest.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
        int maxPosition = sPanelTest.getMaximumVerticalScrollPosition();
        int currentPosition = sPanelTest.getVerticalScrollPosition();
        if(currentPosition == maxPosition)
            Window.alert("Tadam !"); // end of the scroll

    }
});
```

Doc of [ScrollPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html).

[Another example of use](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~ScrollPanel).